# Android recyclerview scroll to top

Tags: java, android

This is my onCreate that handles the adapter, LinearLayoutManager and etc.
I tried every single option to try to scroll it to the top but could not.
I even tried to create my own custom LinearLayoutManager.

```
//Reson for static to call from a static method to scroll it up
private static RecyclerView taskRecyclerView;
private FirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter;
private static LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasklist, container, false);



    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    taskRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_mainTask);
    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userAccount.getId());


    firebaseAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(TaskObject.class, R.layout.one_task, TaskViewHolder.class, databaseRef.child("Task"), getContext());

    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);


    taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
    taskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    relativeLayoutAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    //Listen for any data change
    databaseRef.child("Task").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //onDataChange called so remove progress bar

            //make a call to dataSnapshot.hasChildren() and based
            //on returned value show/hide empty view

            //use helper method to add an Observer to RecyclerView

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    databaseRef.child("Task").keepSynced(true);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: why you reverse your LLM? would you like to scroll to bottom every time something new added to bottom of recyclerview; Like messaging app?

Comment: I want the latest one to always be at the top. That is why I reverse it.

Comment: Can you show an example with UI? if you want add item to top of the recycler view you do not have to reverse LLM, you have to reverse Array. explain it with Image if you can. I'm not sure what is your problem.

Comment: I would like to scroll to the top every time an Item is added so the latest item is at the top while the older one at the bottom.

Comment: `linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);` could this be causing the problem ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try `taskRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0)` or `taskRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(your_position)`?

RecyclerView does not implement any scrolling logic in `taskRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(your_position)` and `taskRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0)` is more specific and it goes to specific index depending implemented layout, in your case is linear.

Comment: Tried `taskRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(your_position)` and `taskRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0)` this work. Can you explain why?

Comment: RecyclerView does not implement any scrolling logic in `taskRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(your_position)` and `taskRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0)` is more specific and it goes to specific index depending implemented layout, in your case is linear.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling to specific items is a tricky part with RecyclerView but below code helps to scroll

**Method for Smooth Scrolling**

```kotlin
fun Context.getSmoothScroll(): LinearSmoothScroller {
        return object : LinearSmoothScroller(this) {
            override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START
            }
        }
    }
```

**Apply Smooth scrolling to RecyclerView**

```kotlin
fun RecyclerView.scrollToPositionSmooth(int: Int) {
        this.layoutManager?.startSmoothScroll(this.context.getSmoothScroll().apply {
            targetPosition = int
        })
    }
```

**Apply Scrolling without Smooth to RecyclerView (Fast)**

```kotlin
fun RecyclerView.scrollToPositionFast(position: Int) {
        this.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(position)
    }
```

**Code to use**

```kotlin
itemFilteredRecyclerView.scrollToPositionFast(0) //Normal Scroll
itemFilteredRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0) //Smooth Scroll
```

**Extra Information:**
You can replace ..(0) with your position need to get scrolled.

Complete code: [Link](https://gist.github.com/merlinJeyakumar/08a7d49fa63ae191e840b221330ab757)

Answer (score -1):

Adding the code below works too.

`linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);`