# How to scroll to an item at specific position (that is not in view), in recycler view in android?

Tags: android

I have a list of images in a recycler view with a Horizontal Linear Layout. I want to programmatically scroll to say position = 20, while the image at that position is not in view. 
I have tried using:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

but this only scrolls if the item is in view. I have also tried using `smoothScrollBy(x,y)` and `getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, position);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android recyclerview scroll to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655486/android-recyclerview-scroll-to-top)

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36569778/5167909

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin Please read the description of my question, I have already tried that solution and it does not work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are doing something wrong there. I've tested that method on both orientations and is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:

```
yourRecyclerViewObject.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(itemPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and using delay worked for me

```
recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
      recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
   }
},300);
```