# How to make a "Scroll To Top" Button on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout

How could I place this function to when the button is clicked, it should scroll to the top of the view and refresh the recyclerview layout (like pull to refresh but on click), is it possible?

Like, when we're navigating through the *app/website* we scroll down and has a button to click and **go back to the top** (scroll up) of the page. But I want to do that and also when the button is clicked do a layout refresh to the recyclerview.

If it's not possible, then a **back to the top function** is highly accepted and I'm grateful for your help.

**Like this one in the red circle:** If you don't know, Twitter has this function to when click the *bird icon* it scroll up the page to the top.

[image: Twitter homescreen]

I'm using a call fragment (fragment_home) to show up the recyclerView, but the button I want to call the action is in my FeedActivity.class then, how could I make a function to do it from another activity class? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android recyclerview scroll to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655486/android-recyclerview-scroll-to-top)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for scroll recyclerview to top:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

Use this code for scroll NestedScrollView to top:

```
nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to reload the Fragment that contains the RecyclerView.  You can achieve this by creating a navigation loop.  Assuming that you have the Jetpack Navigation component in your project and your RecyclerView is in myFragment, you can do something like:

```
    fun doRefresh() {
        Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.action_myFragment_to_myFragment)
    }
```

Comment: Why reloading the whole fragment though? when you can just write `recyclerview.scrollToPosition(0)`!

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to reload the page/Fragment

Comment: The most efficient way to refresh the RecyclerView will be to implement DiffUtil 
  [link]https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil[link]

Comment: here is the link [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter)